# WxMaxima: how to plot functions defined on surfaces

Tags: plot, wxmaxima, plot3d

Is it possible to plot with WxMaxima a function defined on a surface of R^3?

The outcome I would like is to see the surface (say a sphere), colored according to the values that the function takes on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might consider asking on the maxima-discuss list, which has most of the traffic for Maxima. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss Aside from that, one approach might be to look at how Gnuplot handles that, and then figure out how to generate that output in Maxima, if Maxima doesn't already have this capability. Sorry I can't be more helpful.